# Can videojs play videos Swiffy videos?

Tags: flash, html5-video, video.js, google-swiffy

Can [videojs](http://videojs.com/) play videos coverted by [Google Swiffy](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the creator of Video.js, I highly doubt it. Video.js takes the source file URL and passes it to the playback technology (HTML5/Flash/YouTube player), and requires the playback tech to have an API for controlling the video. So unless you can take the result of Swiffy and use it as the source of a video tag, then the answer is no.